# Fill, opacity, strokeColor and strokeWidth in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have dynamically added a CSS class as follows:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.id = "highlightSegment";
var text = ".highlightStyle { fill:" + fill + ";opacity:" + opacity + ";stroke:" + strokeColor + ";stroke-width:" + strokeWidth + "+ }";
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
if (style.styleSheet) {   // for IE
    style.styleSheet.cssText = text;
} else {                // others
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
    style.appendChild(textnode);
}
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
h.appendChild(style);
```

in css is,

```
var text = ".highlightStyle { fill:" + fill + ";opacity:" + opacity + ";stroke:" + strokeColor + ";stroke-width:" + strokeWidth + "+ }";
```

`fill`, `opacity`, `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` are variable which changed dynamically. Those attributes are working fine in all browser except IE8.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check on [How to Simulate CSS3 box-shadow in IE6-8 Without JavaScript.](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/).

I haven't tested it but worth a shot.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=0),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=90),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=180),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=270);
```

## EDIT:

I am not suggesting to stop there on the Shadow but dig down to the DXImageTransform.Microsoft class which is elaborated more in [Static Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539(v=vs.85).aspx).  This only works on IE5.5 to IE8.

Comment: this is shadow not a fill color

Comment: well the DXImageTransform.Microsoft has more to it than just the Shadow.